# Running Docker script application inside a container

Tags: python, docker, redis

I'm new to Docker and containers - I've got a Python 3 script that pulls data from a web site based on command line parameters and prints the results. It uses Redis for caching data if there's no network connection available. The Dockerfile I have looks like this

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get -y install redis-server && apt-get install -y python3-pip python3.5-dev build-essential
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
CMD ["pn.py"]
```

I'm able to build the image, but when I start the container it presumably runs the Python command to run the script inside the container and exits, and as a consquence I cannot see the results from the host.

The script requires command line inputs, otherwise it will fail. How can these be specified as part of a single Docker run command I can use to run the script from the host?

Alternatively how can I start the container without calling the script, and instead run the script manually inside the running container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do with the results.

Assume the following:

- the `ENTRYPOINT` line tells the image what should be executed when you start the container. That will be `PID 1`.
- when that line exists, the `CMD` content is used as argument(s) to the `ENTRYPOINT`.
- docker containers always exit when their main task (PID 1) exits.

Basically your docker is doing what it is told to do. If you want it to keep running, you should give a task that won't exit as `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD` (if `ENTRYPOINT` was not present).

For manually start the container on a `shell` mode and see what happens, you can run it as:

```
docker run -ti [OPTIONS] [CONTAINER_NAME] bash
```

and then you'll be in a shell "into" the container, so you can run the script manually:

```
#~ python3 pn.py
```

Comment: OK thanks. The command `apt-get -y install redis-server` in the second line of the `Dockerfile` is supposed to install `redis-server` and start it automatically, but this does not work. After entering the container `service redis-server status` tells me it is not running. This happens even after I changed the `Dockerfile` to add the additional line `service redis-server restart` immediately after the `apt-get update` and install line. How can I fix this?

Comment: You have misunderstood the concept of the `Dockerfile`. You won't get a service running from one line to another. The `Dockerfile` creates a `docker images` which is composed by one or more `Layers`. Each line of your `Dockerfile` creates a new layer. Think of that as static members of a class, and the resulting image is a class. The container you run after, using this image, is line an instance of this class, or an object. You can't expect services to keep running while building the image with the Dockerfile.

Comment: Also, I would change the line `RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get -y install redis-server && apt-get install -y python3-pip python3.5-dev build-essential` to `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y redis-server  python3-pip python3.5-dev build-essential` to simplify.